# Reading the attributes of the iframe content - doesn't work

Tags: jquery, iframe

```
    jQuery(".single_writing").each(function(){
                   jQuery(this).click(function(){
                        jQuery("#thisTickets").val("");
                        jQuery("#my_iframe").contents().find('.ticket_id').each(function(){
                           jQuery(this).click(function(){
                              if (jQuery(this).attr("checked")==true){ 
                                  jQuery("#thisTickets").val(jQuery("#thisTickets").val()+jQuery(this).attr("id")+", ");
                              }
                           });
                        });
                 })
    });
```

Any ideas?

What I want to achieve is find out which checkboxes are checked in my iframe and I want to know their id's, when I submit the form from my document (form in the main document, not the form in iframe)

Comment: try by replacing jQuery( by $(

Comment: since, "$" is an alias of "jQuery", it isn't the matter here...

Comment: jQuery error was about something else (old code), so no I have the above, which don't work and any errors in firebug...

Comment: Is the iframe on the same domain of the file where you are making this call?

Comment: yes, it is on the same domain, I'm aware of "same origin policy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since jQuery is asynchronous language, the commands aren't executed sequentially.

So, the problem in my code was, that it operated in the iframe, but with its previews value, before the clicking.

So I had to separate this code.

Now I have something like this and it works perfectly:

```
    $(".single_writing").each(function(){
                   $(this).click(function(){
                       ....
                 })
    });
    $("#my_iframe").mouseover(function(){
        $("#my_iframe"").contents().find('.ticket_id').each(function(){
            $(this).click(function(){
                if ($(this).attr("checked",true)){ 
                    $("#thisTickets").val($("#thisTickets").val()+$(this).attr("name")+", ");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code should give you the checked checkboxes from your iframe when called from document (and not the iframe)

```
$("#my_iframe").contents().find("input:checkbox").attr("checked",true)
```

Comment: thanks for help, but I found out the answer and it has other solution

Comment: OK, I shared it, well, I know It took so long :)